# knockoutjs MVC 4 computed values

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I have the following viewModel

```
        var viewModel = new myViewModel([{
            Name: "Name",
            price: 32,
            tax: 22,
        }, {
            Name: "Name",
            price: 32,
            tax: 22,
        }]);
```

I have a data-bind to

```
       <tbody data-bind='foreach: personInfo'>
```

and input:

```
        <td>
        <input class='required' data-bind='value: Name'/>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input class='required' data-bind='value: Price'/>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input class='required' data-bind='value: Tax'/>
        </td>
```

and I want to get the computed value for price and then for tax however I am not successful. :(

```
        self.totalSurcharge = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; self.PersonInfo().length; i++)
        total += self.PersonInfo[i].price;
        return total;
        });
```

any idea?

UPDATE:

something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hamsaya/9XNDH/1/

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of where PersonInfo is declared, and also describe where you're attempting to define the totalSurcharge computed observable?

Comment: suppose this http://jsfiddle.net/hamsaya/9XNDH/1/ I want where it says total of price here. That is how I want to calculate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the below code which is working fine,

Modify your html as below:

```
 <tr>
     <td> Total of price here</td>
     <td data-bind="text:totalPrice"></td>
 </tr>
```

Add below Computed Observable in your script to calculate total price:

```
self.totalPrice = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
    var totalAmount = null;
    for(var i=0 , j=self.gifts().length ; i < j ; i++ )
    {
         totalAmount =Number(totalAmount)+ Number(self.gifts()[i].price);
    }
    if(totalAmount == 0){
        totalAmount = '0.00'
        }
    return totalAmount;
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you notice the answer below is working too. I found it yesterday I didn't have to use read.

Answer (score 2):

interesting enough they have to update the site:

here is the answer.

```
    self.totalSurcharge = ko.computed(function () {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < gifts.length; i++)
    total =total+ gifts[i].price;
    return total;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you need to use parantheses to access the KO-wrapped observable array before using an indexer to access data from it:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Try replacing

```
self.PersonInfo[i].price
```

with

```
self.PersonInfo()[i].price
```

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/hamsaya/9XNDH/1/ might better let you know how I want to do it. I tried this it did not work :(